# CLion CMake application cannot resolve mutex

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I am trying to build a c++ project with [CLion IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/) in windows. One of the cpp file includes `mutex`. but seems clion can't find this. It says

> No member named 'mutex' in namespace 'std'

Code snippet that showing this error is

```
typedef std::lock_guard<std::mutex> my_lock;
static std::mutex my_mutex_;
```

And my CMakeLists.txt file contains

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(webrtc_aec)
FIND_PACKAGE(JNI REQUIRED)
include_directories(${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -msse4.1")
```

When I am building this project it says.

> error: 'mutex' is not a member of 'std'

I am not sure what did I do wrong. How can I get rid of this error ?

**EDIT:** when I am building this it also says

> -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_DEPENDS_USE_COMPILER=FALSE -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles"

**EDIT 2:** Minimal Example with Logger class

**Logger.h**

```
#ifndef LOGGER_H
#define LOGGER_H

#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

class Logger {
public:
    static void init(const char*);
    static void close();

    static void debug(std::string fileName, int lineNumber, const std::string& message);
    static void info(std::string fileName, int lineNumber, const std::string& message);
    static void warn(std::string fileName, int lineNumber, const std::string& message);
    static void error(std::string fileName, int lineNumber, const std::string& message);

private:
    static void log(std::string fileName, int lineNumber, const std::string& message, int type);
    static std::string timeString(time_t time, std::string format);

    static std::ofstream log_stream;
    
    static bool initialized;

    static const int DEBUG = 0;
    static const int INFO = 1;
    static const int WARN = 2;
    static const int ERR = 3;
};

#endif /* LOGGER_H */
```

**Logger.cpp**

```
#include "Logger.h"

/* DEFINITIONS BELOW */


typedef std::lock_guard<std::mutex> logger_lock;
static std::mutex logger_mutex_;
static const char* log_file;

std::string Logger::timeString(time_t time, std::string format) {
    char time_format_buffer[64];
    std::strftime(time_format_buffer, sizeof(time_format_buffer), format.c_str(), std::localtime(&time));
    return time_format_buffer;
}

void Logger::init(const char* file_name) {
    //std::cout << "Getting log file name\n";
    if (!initialized) {
        //std::cout << "Log file name: " << filename << std::endl;
        log_file = file_name;
        log_stream.open(log_file, std::ios::app);
        initialized = true;
    }
    else {
        Logger::log("Logger.cpp", __LINE__, "An attempt was made to reinitialize the logger!", Logger::WARN);
    }
}

void Logger::close() {
    if (initialized) {
        log_stream.close();
        initialized = false;
    }
    else {
        Logger::log("Logger.cpp", __LINE__, "An attempt was made to close an unititialized logger!", Logger::WARN); // This is stupid.
    }
}

void Logger::log(std::string fileName, int lineNumber, const std::string& message, int type) {
    std::string prefix, timestamp;

    switch (type) {
    case Logger::DEBUG:
        prefix = "[D ";
        break;
    case Logger::WARN:
        prefix = "[W ";
        break;
    case Logger::INFO:
        prefix = "[I ";
        break;
    case Logger::ERR:
        prefix = "[E ";
        break;
    default:
        prefix = "[? ";
    }

    timestamp = timeString(std::time(NULL), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
    logger_lock ll(logger_mutex_);
    log_stream << prefix << timestamp << " - " << fileName << ":" << lineNumber << "] - " << message << std::endl;
}

void Logger::debug(std::string fileName, int lineNumber, const std::string& message) {
    Logger::log(fileName, lineNumber, message, Logger::DEBUG);
}

void Logger::info(std::string fileName, int lineNumber, const std::string& message) {
    Logger::log(fileName, lineNumber, message, Logger::INFO);
}

void Logger::warn(std::string fileName, int lineNumber, const std::string& message) {
    Logger::log(fileName, lineNumber, message, Logger::WARN);
}

void Logger::error(std::string fileName, int lineNumber, const std::string& message) {
    Logger::log(fileName, lineNumber, message, Logger::ERR);
}

std::ofstream Logger::log_stream;
bool Logger::initialized = false;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "one of the cpp file includes mutex"? Do you `#include <mutex>` header in the source file where you are using the std::mutex?

Comment: Yes. I did that right.

Comment: I am using windows

Comment: I am not sure about that. How can I check ?

Comment: It says... -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_DEPENDS_USE_COMPILER=FALSE -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles"

Comment: Which version of MinGW are you using? Which compiler (version) does your project use? There are quite a few posts about the problem for older versions of MinGW; I cannot tell, if this is still an issue for more recent versions, since I'm not using MinGW for compilation on windows myself... Maybe CLion supports MSVC tools too? For msvc the standard lib should be implemented properly, unless you're using a quite ancient version...

Answer (score 0):

"One of the cpp file includes mutex"

Your compiler tells us this is not enough. `<mutex>` must be included before the first use of `std::mutex` in *each* Translation Unit. FYI, a Translation Unit is a .cpp together with anything it directly or indirectly includes. That means the `#include <mutex>` might even be needed in your own .h. This is quite common for instance when a class declaration in a .h contains a `std::mutex` member.

Comment: I have tried putting
1.  #include <mutex> in .h file
2. #include <mutex> in .cpp file
3.  #include <mutex> in both files.
But still no luck

Comment: @SodrulAminShaon: Time for a minimal example, then.

Comment: I have edited my question and shared my logger class

Comment: @SodrulAminShaon: That's about 50 times bigger than minimal. Do you get the same error message if your .cpp file has literally just 2 lines; `#include "Logger.h" static std::mutex logger_mutex_;`. ? Also make you .h minimal.

Comment: yes even with the 2 lines in .cpp and 

#ifndef LOGGER_H
#define LOGGER_H

#include <cstdlib>
#include <mutex>


#endif /* LOGGER_H */

  in the .h file, it shows the same error.

Comment: I guess I have to do something with my mingw installation. But I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

As @fabian stated. I had to install latest [MingW](http://win-builds.org/doku.php) . Then changed the clion setting as below.

1. File -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Toolchains -> Add (Point here the newly installed mingw and put it up so that it sets to default)
2. File -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> CMake -> (Profiles) Release -> Toolchain (Make sure newly mingw is pointed)

This solved my issue. Thanks. :)